# Can Kafka ProducerInterceptor filter records?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka supports the concept of Interceptors, which sit between Kafka and a process that consumes or produces records, such that the records that are read from or written to Kafka can be mutated or custom logging can be performed.

From what I can see, the [ConsumerInterceptor](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerInterceptor.html) allows for records to be filtered, in that it returns a [ConsumerRecords](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecords.html) object and an implementation could remove (i.e. censor) items from the container class before passing the records to a consumer.

A [ProducerInterceptor](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/javadocs/index.html) only takes and returns a [ProducerRecord](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html), rather than something like an `Optional<ProducerRecord>`.  What happens if the record that is returned by this method is null?  The use case is wanting to prevent the writing of records to Kafka - is this supported by simply dropping the records being written by returning null, or would one have to mutate the input object and zero its fields?

Answer (score 0):

You may get a SerializationException since the interception will happen before serialization given you'd need to do this onSend. If you handle the null case it might work out for you but you'll need to decide if this is the right thing to do. If you want to send essentially a null record to Kafka in the event of filtering occurring then this makes some sense. If you just want to drop the record, better to just put the filtering logic in the producer itself instead of intercepting.